# Forward declaration in XAML to resolve circular dependency of DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, hierarchicaldatatemplate, datatemplateselector

I want to use a HierarchicalDataTemplate with a DataTemplateSelector but I get trouble with the order:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AnySource}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}" >
        <Label Content="A" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateB">
        <Label Content="B" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <viewmodel:MyTemplateSelector 
        TemplateA="{StaticResource TemplateA}" 
        TemplateB="{StaticResource TemplateB}" 
        x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" />

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="TemplateC"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherSource}"
                              ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}">
        <Label Content="C" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TreeView 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SomeList}}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateC}"/>
</Grid>
```

MyTemplateSelector depends on TemplateA and TemplateA depends on MyTemplateSelector. I get a System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException at Runtime. Is there a way of forward declaration in XAML or is there a different solution?

**Solution:**
I've found the Solution: I don't need to set the TemplateSelector in TemplateA because it is set in the parent DataTemplate. Sometimes it can be so simple...

Comment: there must be some better way of doing what you are trying to do... can you share where are your applying your templates and what is the Data structure you want to bind?

Comment: I've added some more information but I think they don't help. The data structure to bind is to complex to show it here in a simple way but I know: I need the DataTemplateSelector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[It seems that you overcame the issue by not loading the resource. I'll still post the answer for future readers]

You can use `DynamicResource` instead of `StaticResource`.

This only works if you populate a dependency property, i.e. `Binding.Converter="{DynamicResource MyConverter}"` will not work since `Binding.Converter` is not a dependency property.